# Derivative estimation?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a function $\varphi(t)\in C^1(R)$. For $a>0, t\geq 0$ and $s\in[t-a,t]$, we set 
$$f(t,s)=\sup_{s\leq \xi\leq t}\varphi(\xi)$$ 
How to formulate or estimate the derivative 
$\frac{\partial f(t,s)}{\partial t}$.